# Jodd Madvoc: Result Mapping to JSPs under a folder say WEB-INF

Tags: jodd

For an action method:

```
@Action("/hello/${name}")
public String world() {
   value = "Hello "+name+"!";
   return "#world";
}
```

how to render the JSP `/hello/world.jsp` under `WEB-INF`? Is there a config alternative to add a *prefix* to `resultPath`.

Thanks
Aanand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such prefix (nice idea, though! We will add it in the next release :).

Meanwhile, you can modify the result very easily by overriding the `ResultMapper`:

```
public class MyResultMapper extends ResultMapper {

@Override
public String resolveResultPath(ActionConfig cfg, String resultValue) {
        String resultPath = super.resolveResultPath(cfg, resultValue);
        resultPath = "/WEB-INF" + resultPath;
        return resultPath;
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to register your result mapper. You can do this in several ways; one way might be to follow these steps:

1) Add your custom Madvoc `WebApplication` by registering it in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>madvoc</filter-name>
    <filter-class>jodd.madvoc.MadvocServletFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>madvoc.webapp</param-name>
        <param-value>....MyWebApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
...
</filter>
```

2) and then implement it:

```
public class MyWebApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public void registerMadvocComponents() {
        super.registerMadvocComponents();
        registerComponent(MyResultMapper.class);
    }
```

Done, you don't have to change any of your Madvoc actions, all JSPs are now searched under the WEB-INF (or whatever folder you put there).

EDIT: as promised, see [latest commit](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/commit/a7cb9710a8508000bff0b7908846650b635d60fb), it adds new Madvoc configuration flag.

Comment: thanks ɹoƃı. will try the latest from repo and also the above WebApplication implementation